# Mean reversion factor logic

Tags: mean-reversion

I have a hard time understanding the caveats of mean reversion factor logic.

Let's imagine a mean reverting process:

$$
dx_t = θ(μ−x_t)dt+e_t​
$$

Where θ is the "mean reversion" coefficient, μ is the long-term mean or average.

Theory says for a given deviation from the mean, the force pulling x_t back towards the mean is stronger when θ is larger.
If I OLS regress this thing, then θ would only signify how strongly the deviation from mean would impact change x_t.

If θ>0 (according to most theories), then increase in deviation would result in θ*(μ−x_t) change in dx_t, but **not** mean that it would revert back with this coefficient. Am i wrong? Why do they say it is mean reverting?

Comment: are you sure that it's not $dx_{t} = \theta(\mu - x_{t-1})dt + e_{t}$ ? If so, then I can explain it. Assume that is the case. Then, we can re-write as $dx_{t} =  -\theta(x_{t-1} - \mu)dt + e_{t}$ ? This says that, when $x_{t-1}$ is further away from $\mu$, then, since $\theta$ is positive, the change of $x_t$ in the next period will be negative so that $x_t$ is expected to move in the direction ( relative to $\mu$) opposite to where it moved ( relative to $\mu$ ) previously.